# R:-Auto increment field in the table

Tags: mysql, database, r

I insert some row to the table using R script
like,

```
dbWriteTable(con,"MyTable",MyDataFrame,overwrite=F,append = T,row.names=FALSE)
```

It insert 744 rows.
I have an auto increment field in the table.
In MyDataFrame (dataframe which i want to insert to the table) the auto increment field is set to as NA.
When I insert the data the auto increment field will updated like 1,2,3.....,744.

My problem is when i insert new row in the table the auto increment field will updated as 1024.

ie) When I run the code   `dbWriteTable(con,"MyTable",MyDataFrame,overwrite=F,append = T,row.names=FALSE)` again, then the auto increment field will start with 1024 and so on...

What is the reason for that?
How to solve this issue?

Comment: List the setup and the packages being used. List: structure of MyDataFrame;  and of MyTable.

Comment: @DWin If I insert any row direct from the table after insert some rows using R ,it set the auto increment to 1024